# How to understand the term "non-blocking" of script tag in spec?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, specifications, w3c

In the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics-scripting.html#non-blocking):

> The third is a flag indicating whether the element will "non-blocking". Initially, script elements must have this flag set. It is unset by the HTML parser and the XML parser on script elements they insert. In addition, whenever a script element whose "non-blocking" flag is set has an async content attribute added, the element’s "non-blocking" flag must be unset.

Sorry,I can't understand what it means.There are some questions of this:

1.

> The third is a flag indicating whether the element will "non-blocking". Initially, script elements must have this flag set

"Initially" means there is a property in `HTMLScriptElement class` named `non-blocking` and default is `true` or it means it's `true` when the script element created or instantiated before parsered by HTML parser?

2.

> It is unset by the HTML parser and the XML parser on script elements they insert.

The "insert" means that the script element insert to the document by using `document.write` or the [insert](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-node-insert) operation?

3.

> In addition, whenever a script element whose "non-blocking" flag is set has an async content attribute added, the element’s "non-blocking" flag must be unset.

The `async` links to the [async attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics-scripting.html#element-attrdef-script-async),but there is a word "content",so what it exactly means?The attribute or the content fetched from server or local?

And if it means content,does it representes the HTML Parser will continue to parse the subsequent bytes of the script element before the async content added?(I write some tests,I think this is wrong)

4.And the most important,does "non-blocking" means not blocking the IO, fetch resource, update layout, repaint etc like we usually talk about?Or there is some else meaning?And the spec says that "Initially, script elements must have this flag set",but we ofen consider the `script` is "blocking"(exactly when executed),so I am in doubt when I first read this and so now.Could anyone clarify my doubt?

5.Finally,is there any implemention(exactly I mean the src code which can be debug conveniently) of the spec?I think based in chrome is better,sorry,I am not say others is not good,just because I only install chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't follow the distinction. What functional difference would it make which of those an implementation chose?
2. The insert operation. `document.write` doesn't insert to the document. It injects characters into the input byte stream that the parser processes.
3. In HTML5 spec parlance, there are two types of "attribute". "Content attribute" and "IDL attribute". A "content attribute" is what you put in markup: `<script async>` is the async content attribute. An "IDL attribute" is what most people think of as a property in JavaScript `myScriptElement.async`.
4. It means not blocking the parser thread. The parser takes characters from the input stream and creates elements, text node objects etc. When the parser is blocked it stops consuming characters from the input stream. (Although it might look-ahead in the input stream to guess whether it's going be asked to fetch other resources, and speculatively fetch them anyway). When the `</script>` tag is seen, if non-blocking flag is unset, the parser will not consume any further characters from the current input stream until the script has been fetched and run. This allows the script to include `document.write` to inject characters into the input stream such that they will be parsed next.
5. Both Chrome (blink) and Firefox (gecko) are open source, but personally I've not tried inspecting either code base in any detail so can't advise how difficult either is. And it's probably quite a personal preference anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Now I think I get it.